# How to recover a file replaced by another file with the same name and size

Tags: windows, data-recovery, file-recovery

A small file has been replaced by another file which has exactly the same name and size. I want to know if the original file can be recovered.

NOTE: Windows operating system.

Comment: Do you mean "overwritten" as in you know the same file was written to the same place on the disk, or do you mean you "saved as" with the same filename as an existing file?  What application and what filesize?

Comment: I'm a pretty big fan of [WinUndelete](http://www.winundelete.com/?rid=google&kid=wu0901). It's worth a shot, I think. If you've saved a bunch more files to the drive since this incident though, you can kiss it goodbye.

Comment: A New file was written on the Old one with the same name and size, the contents of the two file are different but size exactly the same; 970 bytes.

Comment: If you know for a fact that the file was written to the same part of the disk, then there is nothing to be done.  Do you know this for a fact, or are you just referring to "save as"?

Comment: If the exact application was “saved as”, does it mean that the old file is NOT overwritten physically. Sorry for late response; English is not my native one.

Comment: If new file was "saved as" with the same name, then the file **was** overwritten. If it was **saved as** with a different name, then original file deleted and new one renamed, then it wasn't overwritten (IMHO)

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/515906/is-there-any-way-to-restore-recover-a-file-that-was-saved-over-to-its-last-versi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. Deleted files can be recovered in some cases. But this can only be done if the file has not been overwritten. Once the file has been overwritten there is no software recovery. There are studies of methods for low level data recovery with the use of electron microscope, but this is very expensive, always leads to the destruction of the entire HDD and is not feasible unless for forensics.

You did not provide much information about the particular file. If you are talking about a document created with one of the popular processing applications (word, open-office, etc) you might have a slim chance of finding a backup copy or old version created automatically by the app.

Comment: Well just because the file was 'overwritten' according to the folder structure doesn't mean it was overwritten according to the filesystem technically speaking. That data could still be there, and the new file could be saved on a different part of the drive. If the OP hasn't done any or hardly any disk write operations there's a decent chance that the file could be there.

Comment: I completely agree with you @Catatonic27. I have posted my answer based on the original question that literally says **overwritten**. I did not want to go into assumptions about what might have happened. Its up to OP to provide more detail

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I assumed based on the context that 'overwritten' mean that Windows asked the OP if they wanted to replace the existing file, etc...

Comment: Any way I would like to try recovering the old file, maybe it is NOT overwritten physically. Do you suggest any utilities?

Comment: You can try [WinHex](http://www.winhex.com/winhex/). It is extremely powerful. But it may take you hours or even days to thoroughly parse the entire hard drive. And you need some skill to use this tool.